# Complex functions are continuous and differential when their real and imaginary components are continuous and differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.  I need to show that $f(z)$ is continuous if both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous and differentiable if both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are differentiable.

What's the most efficient way to do the problem?  Is there a way around using the limit definition?

Comment: Do you know the definition of complex differentiability?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the "if" with an "iff". In the final analysis the various claims follow from the fact that for all $i\in[n]$ the triangle inequality gives
$$|x_i-y_i|\leq|x-y|\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k-y_k|\ .$$
This implies that for any vector-valued function $t\mapsto {\bf f}(t)$ one has
$$\lim_{t\to t_0}{\bf f}(t)={\bf a}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \lim_{t\to t_0}f_k(t)=a_k\quad(1\leq k\leq n)\ ,$$
whatever the intended limit $t\to t_0$ may be.

Comment: Christian Blatter, do you interpret $f$'s differentiability to mean [$\mathbb R^2$-differentiability rather than $\mathbb C$-differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576349/)?

Comment: Right so $f$ is $\mathbb C$-diff iff $u$ and $v$ are too and then $f$ is $\mathbb R^2$-diff iff $u$ and $v$ are too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870926